# How to debug and solve the Binding issue with ComboBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, debugging, combobox

I'm using ComboBox in my xaml but i'm unable to visualise any data on the view. It just shows empty text file and empty dropdown.

I have tried to debug the problem with help of [these tips](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2013/12/11/wpf-data-binding-debug/). However, I haven't been able to solve the issue.

Here's the **databindingDebugConverter**:

```
public class DatabindingDebugConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value1, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Debugger.Break();
        return value1;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value2, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Debugger.Break();
        return value2;
    }
}
```

- The Value1 is returning in ComboBox `Text=` case a `"Field Device"`  `(object{string})`
- and on the `ItemsSource=` value1 is returning `object{Device}` with the fields of `Category` and reference to `Category1` object holding `CategoryId` in it.
- For the `SelectedValue` a `"Field Device"`  `(object{string})` is once again returned.

Here is the ComboBox xaml:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="ProductCategoryComboBox" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="21.96" Margin="0,20,10.5,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"
          Text="{Binding DeviceDatabaseViewModel.SelectedDevice.Category, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource debugConverter}}" 
          IsEditable="False"
          ItemsSource="{Binding DeviceDatabaseViewModel.SelectedDevice, Converter={StaticResource debugConverter}}" 
          SelectedValue="{Binding DeviceDatabaseViewModel.SelectedDevice.Category, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource debugConverter}}"
          SelectedValuePath="CategoryId"
          DisplayMemberPath="Category" />
```

Similar binding including `TextBlock` fields within the xaml are working fine and displaying the string values from the `SelectedDevice`.

**EDIT**

The `selectedDevice` is referred from a `dataGrid`:

```
private Device _selectedDevice;
public Device SelectedDevice
{
    get
    {
        return _selectedDevice;
    }
    set
    {
        if (_selectedDevice == value)
        {
            return;
        }
        _selectedDevice = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedDevice");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Combobox is for choosing an Item out of a Collection (for example List or ObservableCollection if you want the UI to recognize changes in the collection).
You do not bind to a collection here:

ItemsSource="{Binding DeviceDatabaseViewModel.SelectedDevice, Converter={StaticResource debugConverter}}"

Instead of binding to the SelectedDevice you would need to bind to an ObservableCollection AllDevices or something like this to which you then could bind the ItemsSource.

Here an example for something you could bind to:

```
public class DeviceDatabaseViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Device> AllDevices
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public DeviceDatabaseViewModel()
    {
        AllDevices = new ObservableCollection<Device>();
        AllDevices.Add(new Device { Category = 'Computer', CategoryId = 1 }, new Device { Category = 'Tablet', CategoryId = 2 });
    }
}
```

Then using the following binding:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding DeviceDatabaseViewModel.AllDevices, Converter= {StaticResource debugConverter}}"
```

Comment: ah yes, forgot that I needed collection for the `itemsSource`